# Question about the Guard class in CompositeUI Application Block of Microsoft

Tags: .net

Is there anybody use the Guard Class provided by Microsoft in its open source project CompositeUI Application Block?
I noticed that, in the Guard class, there are only some methods to do the argument parameter validating. But as we all know that, in our self codes, there are may be many cases that need to validate some other variable (which is not an argument parameter) or member, and throw exception if the validation is failed. For this cases, why the Guard class not provide some helper class for helping to do that?

Below is the codes of Guard class:

```
//===============================================================================
// Microsoft patterns & practices
// CompositeUI Application Block
//===============================================================================
// Copyright  Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY
// OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT
// LIMITED TO THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
//===============================================================================

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.Utility
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Common guard clauses
 /// </summary>
 public static class Guard
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// Checks a string argument to ensure it isn't null or empty
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="argumentValue">The argument value to check.</param>
  /// <param name="argumentName">The name of the argument.</param>
  public static void ArgumentNotNullOrEmptyString(string argumentValue, string argumentName)
  {
   ArgumentNotNull(argumentValue, argumentName);

   if (argumentValue.Length == 0)
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.StringCannotBeEmpty, argumentName));
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks an argument to ensure it isn't null
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="argumentValue">The argument value to check.</param>
  /// <param name="argumentName">The name of the argument.</param>
  public static void ArgumentNotNull(object argumentValue, string argumentName)
  {
   if (argumentValue == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(argumentName);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Checks an Enum argument to ensure that its value is defined by the specified Enum type.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="enumType">The Enum type the value should correspond to.</param>
  /// <param name="value">The value to check for.</param>
  /// <param name="argumentName">The name of the argument holding the value.</param>
  public static void EnumValueIsDefined(Type enumType, object value, string argumentName)
  {
   if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value) == false)
    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
     Properties.Resources.InvalidEnumValue, 
     argumentName, enumType.ToString()));
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Verifies that an argument type is assignable from the provided type (meaning
  /// interfaces are implemented, or classes exist in the base class hierarchy).
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="assignee">The argument type.</param>
  /// <param name="providedType">The type it must be assignable from.</param>
  /// <param name="argumentName">The argument name.</param>
  public static void TypeIsAssignableFromType(Type assignee, Type providedType, string argumentName)
  {
   if (!providedType.IsAssignableFrom(assignee))
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
     Properties.Resources.TypeNotCompatible, assignee, providedType), argumentName);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the Guard class is to test arguments before they're used.

For Example:

```
public void Store(string ImageName, Image Image)
{
     Guard.ArgumentNotNullOrEmptyString(ImageName, Resources.ImageName);
     Guard.ArgumentNotNull(Image, Resources.Image);

     LocalStore(ImageName, Image);

     if (NextStore != null)
     {
         NextStore.Store(ImageName, Image);          
     }
}
```

So the guard statements are ensuring that both parameters meet the assumptions of the method body.

Note: If you don't want to use the Guard pattern you should probably provide an example (code or description) of what you're trying to achieve rather than posting the Guard class code.